# Event handler calling function repeatedly when used in a IE plugin

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

Developing a plugin for internet explorer.
In the beginning I used the `window.onload` the plugin worked fine as per desired result. The problem occured in the sharepoint where it disabled the `Library tools or ribbon tab`. I used the event handler in order to solve the problem and worked really fine. But now the problem is that whenever i use eventhandler, it calls the function repeatedly eg. called 4 times in a website, 2 times in sharepoint website. I tried several ways posted on internet to call the function only once, it didn't solve my problem.

**Code**

```
function callDOM(obj){
   console.log('Function called!');//is called repeatedly,require only once to be called
}
if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('load',adi,false);
}
else {
    document.addEventlistener('load',adi,false);
}
//function adi is getting called repeatedly
function adi(){
    var tag=document.querySelector('body');
    callDom(tag);
}
```

Using `window.onload` calls the function only once but it does no solve the solution as the plugin should work on sharepoint site.

Comment: Your question has `jQuery` tag. Have you considered `$(window).load();` ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `window.addEventListener` is the W3 spec.  Most versions of IE (if not all, I'm not sure) use the `attachEvent`, non standard method.  Have you tried these differences?

Comment: @Phix: Yea I have tried both , the function adi is called multiple times, but when i use window.onload function, the function is called only once